# How to implement polyfit and polyval Matlab functions in java?

Tags: java, matlab

I'm working to University project. 
I have to implement polyfit and polyval MAtlab functions with Java:

`alpha` contains:

```
-20 -15 -10 -5 0 5 10 15 20 25;
```

`Cz` contains:

```
-0.0933 -.0978 -.0982 -.0784 -.0489 -.0066 .049 .1072 .1283 .13;
```

I need to implement

```
pCzb = polyfit(alpha,Cz,9);
Czb  = polyval(pCzb,Alpha*(180/pi));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you've given the numerical values.

The documentation for [polyfit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) says exactly how Matlab performs the polynomial regression. See the algorithms section.

It boils down to a linear algebra problem, for which you can use e.g. [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/).

Comment: i have matlab program to convert into java program. He uses the rows i wrote and I don't have any idea how to convert into Java

Comment: The numerical inputs don't seem particularly important. You need to perform the computation as I described above.

Comment: ok. isn't there a Java Class or library to solve my problem without implementation?

Comment: Not that I know of. I don't think it will be that difficult to do it with e.g. Apache Commons Math, though.